# Stable and Unstable Manifolds Computation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, dynamical-systems

I want to compute (approximately) the stable and unstable manifolds around the origin of the following system.

$x' = 6x + 8y + (sinx)^2 - y^2$

$y' = 8x - 6y + x^2 + xy$

How can I solve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Just follow the standard procedure.  Do you know how to obtain the linear approximation?  The quadratic correction term?  Cubic? ...

Comment: First of all thanks for the response! Secondly, yes I know how to get linear approximation around the origin. But after that?

Answer (score 2):

Making $y=h(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^k$ over the manifolds we have

$$
\dot y = h_x(x)\dot x
$$

or

$$
8x-6h(x)+x^2 + x h(x) = h_x(x)\left(6x+8h(x)+\left(x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}\right)-h^2(x)\right)
$$

considering $n = 3$ we have after reducing to a null polynomial

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 4 \left(a_1+2\right) \left(2 a_1-1\right) =0\\
 -a_1^3+6 \left(4 a_1+3\right) a_2-1 =0\\
 16 a_2^2+\left(1-4 a_1^2\right) a_2+8 \left(4 a_1+3\right) a_3 =0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and after solving we have

$$
\cases{
h_1(x) = -\frac{1183 x^3}{18000}+\frac{7 x^2}{30}-2 x\\
h_2(x) = -\frac{9 x^3}{16000}+\frac{3 x^2}{80}+\frac{x}{2}
}
$$

Those are two representations for unstable manifolds (in red) depicted in the following figure

[image]

NOTE

$\left(x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}\right)$ represents the first two term series representation for $(\sin x)^2$

Comment: Thnaks for the reply! But because $h(x)$ is tangnet to $E^s$, doesn't mean that the first term of $h(x)$ will be $ax^2$?

Comment: @LegendCero : That happens only if you define $h(x)$ as the offset to the parametrization of the linear manifolds. Note that in the linear coefficient one gets a quadratic polynomial for the first coefficient, similar to the characteristic polynomial, while all other equations are linear in the next unknown coefficient.

Comment: Thanks for the effort to answer me! But, could you explain this to me more? Because I've searched online and on every example I found they use $h(x) = ax^2 + bx^3 + ...$

Comment: Then why don't you include the development which justifies this $h(x)$ in your question? Please. See the comment from @LutzLehmann just above.